# Why is it suggested to use a different service to host static files (like nginx or apache) for django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I've seen many questions on stackoverflow about handling static files in django during deployment. I saw that many answers said something like this - "With debug turned off Django won't handle static files for you any more - your production web server (Apache or something) should take care of that."
Why can't we use the server hosting the django project to host the static files too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static files don't require any kind of logic or processing. It is more efficient to deliver them directly to the end-user directly from disk via a web server, rather than running them through the middle layer of Django. That middle layer (such as gunicorn, uwsgi, or mod_wsgi) is what allows things like views to be processed and for the ORM to connect with a database. Since static files require none of that, bypassing it is the most efficient. The same is true for media files that are uploaded by the end user. Good luck!